# glfw makefile fails upon "generating html documentation" on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, cmake, glfw

I am trying to compile and install glfw 3.1.1 for Ubuntu 14.10. The cmake finished successfully, however, when I go to execute the makefile through `make` it fails at the following:

```
[ 98%] Building C object tests/CMakeFiles/windows.dir/windows.c.o
Linking C executable windows
[ 98%] Built target windows
Scanning dependencies of target docs
[100%] Generating HTML documentation
Error: tag HTML_HEADER: header file `/home/dennis/Documents/LearningOpenGL/glfw-3.1.1/docs/header.html' does not exist
docs/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/build.make:52: recipe for target 'docs/CMakeFiles/docs' failed
make[2]: *** [docs/CMakeFiles/docs] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1184: recipe for target 'docs/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [docs/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

At first I thought that it is failing an optional step but then I realized that I can't compile my test project as it complains about the glfw header:

```
main.cpp:2:24: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! I had to disable the "build documentation" option in the cmake gui.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just skip compiling the doc instead of fix it.

Simply go to `docs/CMakeFiles/docs.dir`, modify the file `build.make`.

For the build target `docs/CMakeFiles/docs:`, change the doxygen command
from:

```
doxygen.exe
```

to

```
doxygen.exe .
```